# Resistance in series

Tags: resistors, series

Resistance drops current but in series circuit, the current remains same. So what happens when two or more resistors are in series?

Comment: Nothing drops current - explain what you mean. Do you understand ohms law?

Comment: Down vote for and incomprehensible question.

Comment: @Andyaka Current is the flow of electron in given time(i=q/t). So if we increase the time that the charges take to flow This will reduce the current(drop in current). Right?

Comment: Zeeshan don't use word "drop"  with current. Actually these guys are thinking that you meant "drop in voltage"  i.e. you mistyped "current"  not the word "drop"  itself.  Actually there was one answer which was explaining all these terminologies  here as answerer understood problems one beginner might have with terminologies especially if English is not his native language.  But it was sadly too down voted,  for unknown reasons,  perhaps it was too "Beginner-friendly"?

Comment: @Deep Even my question is downvoted that i cant even post anymore questions. And i am beginner 18 years old and even the silliest question may help someone clear his confusion idk why people downvoted my question..

Comment: @Deep which answer are you talking about?

Comment: @zeeshan, I understood yr situation & tried raising issue of beginners being handled too hardly, but even in d place where I raided this issue, I was down voted like 20 times(k, was little angry & my language reflected dat, but later I apologised & removed inappropriate words)& no one was willing to give constructive suggestions & were just protecting existing situations. They don't understand how adversely it affects beginner. Instead, many searched my profile & downvoted 4 yr old things & also attacked me on personal basis. Anyways, I tried to solve your doubt in comment of an answer below.

Comment: @Deep Yeah i totally agree. What can be more adverse for a guy who asks question than to downvote his question enough that i cant ask anymore question on this forum.. People downvote without trying to understand the question and it really sucks. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean "Resistance drops voltage?" Think about water flowing down a stream. Here, the water is analogous the electrical current and the voltage is analogous to the potential energy of the water. Down the stream, potential energy is lower but the amount of flow is the same. In this sense, a resistor in a circuit will drop the voltage across it, but the current flow into that branch is the same as the current existing the branch regardless of the number of resistors in that same branch.

Comment: +1 for a very good analogy that everyone tends to forget about :)

Comment: When using analogies, one should always know whether or not it is applicable in a specific case. I would suggest to be careful with analogies and avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @KingDuken Maybe everyone tends to "forget about" plumbing analogies because they just add to the confusion. Most people have no plumbing experience!

Comment: @pipe Funny that *you* are saying this :)

Comment: I totally understand your answer but i am a little confused that current is flow of electron in given time. So if according to you water analogy, if there is a clogging in the pipeline which is the resistance, it will reduce the flow of water. Amount of water flowing will not be same after adding resistance to the pipe so this means current is reduced. Which is opposed to the series circuit definition.

Comment:  Perhaps analogy is creating more doubts than solving ...

Comment: @zeeshan No analogy can 100% represent the actual phenomenon. I used the analogy to quickly present the concept. I apology for the additional confusion.

Comment: With a fixed applied voltage, you can only push a certain amount of charge (electrons) through a closed loop. According to Consr of Energy and Matter, you cannot create more of the existing electrons. Thus, the amount of charge flowing into the first resistor has to exist the last resistor. This flow is the current.  A series of resistances would drop the voltage along a loop but what comes in has to comes out to create a closed loop

Comment: @J.P. I agree with you completely but the thing that bothers me is the time. As i=q/t, the resistance increase the time required for charges to travel, which results in reduced current.. So amount of charges remain same but the time increases which decreases the current as opposed to the series circuit definition(current is same through out the circuit) . ?

Comment: Current is same through out the circuit "at given instant of time".  If 2 resistors are connected in series,  the current through them will be less than if only single resistor was there  BUT this reduced current will flow through them both and hence current through both resistors will be same at given instant.  Now suppose this current was I2,  and if you add another resistor in series, current will be decreased to say I3,  series circuit means that I3 will flow through all resistors but definitely I3<I2

Comment: If you didn't understand from above comment, think that in class of 10 students,  syllabus for each student remains same.  Similar to current through each resistance remains same in series circuit.  However if you decrease syllabus,  it will decrease for each student but the syllabus one student has to cover is still same as what other 9 students have to cover.  Similarly,  adding resistance will decrease current through each resistor but the current through resistor R1 = current through resistor R2.

Comment: @Deep Thanks for the reply and helping me clear my confusion. Thanks alot.